# Android permissions are ignored

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to obtain a list of bookmarks from the web browser. This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.permissions"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".BookmarkActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

However, when actually trying to obtain the bookmarks, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.browser.provider.BrowserProvider2 from ProcessRecord{854f860 2449:test.permissions/u0a60} (pid=2449, uid=10060) requires com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS or com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
```

Also, if I go to Settings->Apps, find my app in the list, it says: **No permissions requested.**

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2, debugging on a Galaxy Nexus AVD API 18 and I have no idea how to debug this.

Thanks!

EDIT: The output of the `aapt d badging <apt_file>` is:

```
package: name='test.permissions' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0' platformBuildVersionName='4.3.1-1425645'
sdkVersion:'8'
targetSdkVersion:'18'
uses-permission: name='com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS'
application-label:'PermissionsLab'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='PermissionsLab' icon='res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-debuggable
launchable-activity: name='test.permissions.BookmarkActivity'  label='PermissionsLab' icon=''
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen' reason='default feature for all apps'
main
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

Edit 2: The code that does the reading (not written by me):

```
private void loadBookmarks() {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered loadBookmarks()");

    String text = "";

    Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
            projection, null, null, null);

    query.moveToFirst();
    while (query.moveToNext()) {

        text += query.getString(query
                .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
        text += "\n";
        text += query.getString(query
                .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
        text += "\n\n";

    }

    TextView box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    box.setText(text);

    Log.i(TAG, "Bookmarks loaded");
}
```

EDIT 3: Tested on a real Nexus 4 phone with the latest software updates, and although it took about 20 seconds or so, it worked.

Comment: Do you test on Samsung? Might be the phone issue..

Comment: what is the output of `aapt d badging <apk-file>`

Comment: @Lamorak I'm testing on a Galaxy Nexus AVD SDK version 18.

Comment: @ligi I've updated the text with the answer to your question.

Comment: @rhobincu looks good - can you share some code?

Comment: @ligi I'm not installing the apk manually, I'm just hitting Run from the IDE. Might this be a problem with the deployment?

Comment: @rhobincu no - this should not make a difference - can you test on a real-device by any chance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84706/discussion-between-rhobincu-and-ligi).

Comment: If the problem was solved, its likely an export issue, or Build variants issue. My suggestion is to change to "debug variant", close Android studio, then open again and try to launch the APP in the emulated device

Comment: @Bonatti The apk used on the phone was debug variant, and it was built by the Android Studio.

Comment: @rhobincu Then, for the sake of "removing" bugs, change it to production/custom then save, exit Android Studio, then open again, change back, save restart Android Studio again. You are **likely** having some issue, that I could not reproduce. The code appears to be correct and I have no issues (other than the 0 bookmarks, returning a NULL)

Comment: The problem is not solved. I switched to release, tried to run the new build, it told me it's not signed, switched back to debug, clean-build, tried to run the app, it behaves identically: complains about permissions on Galaxy Nexus AVM and it works on a physical Nexus 4.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us where you are running this test, is it a phone, virtual device or if its something else.
[From the "READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS) that permission was added on:

"Added in API level 4"

And you are not using the:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

element, [then from the "elements" documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)
what happens is:

`Caution: If you do not declare this attribute, the system assumes a default value of "1", which indicates that your application is compatible with all versions of Android.`

Comment: I have tried both adding and removing `<uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />` with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, eventually: it was the API version. Initially, the API was set to version 18, proof of that is that the name of the AVM is `Galaxy Nexus API 18`. However, when I created a new AVM for another application, I noticed that the API version had been changed to Andoid MNC - Preview.